# Overloading issue in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, overloading

Guys I am trying to overload a function within a package in Oracle 11gR2.
Functions go like this.

```
Function is_h2h(p_param in number) return boolean
is
 begin
 --some code here
return true;
end;
```

```
Function is_h2h(p_param in number) return number
is
 begin
 --some code here
return 1;
end;
```

So the problem is when I write an `if` statement within another procedure for example

```
if is_h2h(some_param) then --code goes 
end if;
```

the compiler returns `PLS-00307: Too many declarations of 'IS_H2H' match this call`.

So how can I implement this kind of overloading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the signatures different (ignoring the return type) otherwise the compiler won't choose for you.

My first preference would be to give the functions different names, e.g.:

```
function is_h2h_b(p_param in number) return boolean...

function is_h2h_n(p_param in number) return number...
```

If you really really really want to use the same name, you can use a different parameter name - but then you're limited to only using named parameters (which, mind you, is good practice anyway):

```
function is_h2h(p_param_b in number) return boolean...

function is_h2h(p_param_n in number) return number...

if is_h2h(p_param_b => some_param) then...
```

Comment: That is what i wanted. Thank you